# Embedder side pointer compression is DISABLED

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I have built v8 8.4 for Windows as a monolithic static lib, and am trying to get [this sample](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/8.4/samples/hello-world.cc) project running using Visual Studio 2019.

The error I get when the project runs is this:

```
# Fatal error in ../../src/api/api.cc, line 5619
# Embedder-vs-V8 build configuration mismatch. On embedder side pointer compression is DISABLED while on V8 side it's ENABLED.
```

I have tried rebuilding v8 with `v8_enable_pointer_compression` set to `false`, but v8 doesn't build. I would rather it be enabled though if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To turn on pointer compression, compile your app with the compiler flags `V8_COMPRESS_POINTERS` and `V8_31BIT_SMIS_ON_64BIT_ARCH` defined (e.g. set to 1).

(With GCC/Clang, you'd add `-DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS` to the command line; I don't know what the Visual Studio equivalent is, probably there's some build settings configuration thingie.)

Comment: For Visual Studio, you can simply `#define` it or go to project properties | C/C++ | Preprocessor and add it to Preprocessor Definitions.

Comment: For anybody wondering why this doesn't work with newer versions, you need to also add `-DV8_ENABLE_SANDBOX` (source: [Google groups issue](https://groups.google.com/g/v8-users/c/vNlbtTQqs1U/m/K7XAkX9gBAAJ))